# Filter out system package from a ListView

Tags: android, list, listview, filter, system

How do i use this method in a list to filter out the system package from a list?

I currently have this method up:

```
public static List<ApplicationInfo> getInstalledApplication(Context context) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

    List<ApplicationInfo> apps = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(0);
    Collections.sort(apps, new ApplicationInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager));
    return apps;
}
```

Method to filter out system package:

```
private boolean isSystemPackage(ResolveInfo ri){
    return ((ri.activityInfo.applicationInfo.flags&ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)!=0)?true:false;
}
```

Comment: First off, the ternary operator is useless there. Simply return `((ri.activityInfo.applicationInfo.flags&ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)!=0`. So you have that method...nice. And the issue is...?

Comment: But i need to return the system packages but with my collections.sort method

Comment: A comparator only knows how to sort based on your defined ordering. Why don't you post the full code of how you're trying to remove those items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will filter out system packages:

```
public static List<ApplicationInfo> getInstalledApplication(Context context) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> apps = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(0);
    Collections.sort(apps, new ApplicationInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager));
    Iterator<ApplicationInfo> it = apps.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        ApplicationInfo ai = it.next();
        if ((ai.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
    return apps;
}
```